# Error when trying to clear a text bar from a button

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the button (`id="ClearText4"`) to clear a text bar, an error occurs and the page refreshes. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form method="post" target="imgChart4">
    <input type="submit" value="Chart 4" />
    <input type="text" id="ChartBar4" name="ChartBar4" style="width: 286px;"><br>
</form>

<img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 4"/>

<form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText4">
    <button onclick="limpartexto4()">Limpar Texto 4</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function limpartexto4() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText4');
        btn.onclick = function(){ document.getElementById('ChartBar4').value="" };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form method="post" target="imgChart4">
    <input type="submit" value="Chart 4" />
    <input type="text" id="ChartBar4" name="ChartBar4" style="width: 286px;"><br>
</form>

<img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 4"/>

<form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText4">
    <button onclick="limpartexto4()">Limpar Texto 4</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function limpartexto4() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText4');
        btn.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        document.getElementById('ChartBar4').value="" };
    }
</script>
```

Your form has a `method = "post"` that's why this happens.

```
<form method="post" target="imgChart4">
```

Because Form is posted to action="" properties mentioned.

You can use `e.preventDefault()` in the function to avoid default action.

```
function limpartexto4() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText4');
    btn.onclick = function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('ChartBar4').value="" };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have things turned around a little You can remove the form tag around that button and actually get rid of the javascript function as well. Since there's only one thing to do, just put that in the onclick attribute.

```
<form method="post" target="imgChart4">
  <input type="submit" value="Chart 4" />
  <input type="text" id="ChartBar4" name="ChartBar4" style="width: 286px;"><br>
</form>
<img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 4" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ChartBar4').value=''">Limpar Texto 4</button>
```

Comment: Hello mate, I want to apologize for not putting your answer as the solution for a one detail, the option indicated by the other answer with a function will be useful for me because I will add more actions within the function in the future. If I could vote on both answers as a solution, I would vote.